# What is <param,param> in android?

Tags: android

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, String, String >

In this code what is the parameters in <> ? I saw the same thing in many places. But I couldn't figure what it actually mean. I'm trying to populate a listview asynchronously  I'm new to android programming so please help...

Comment: Search for "java generics"

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. check asynctask generic types in the link

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear As Raghu mentined above URL you should have a look at Java Generics.

I just pulled out some Info here.

> A generic class is defined with the following format:
>
> class name { /* ... */ }
>
> The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows
>   the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type
>   variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.
>
> To update the Box class to use generics, you create a generic type
>   declaration by changing the code "public class Box" to `**"public
>   class Box <T>". This introduces the type variable, T, that can be used
>   anywhere inside the class**.`

So In your case,

```
AsyncTask <String, String, String >
```

It says..  These Three String Variables can be used inside your AsynTask .

Hope This will help.